# WebAudio FM modulation

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm trying to modulate `saw` frequency with the pulse from the slow oscillator `sine`. What am I doing wrong? jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/06ua9zLo/

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext;

var context = new AudioContext();

var saw      = context.createOscillator(),
    sine     = context.createOscillator(),
    sineGain = context.createGain();

//set up our oscillator types
saw.type = 'sawtooth';
sine.type = 'sine';

//set the amplitude of the modulation
sineGain.gain.value = 10;

//connect the dots
sine.connect(sineGain);
sineGain.connect(saw.frequency);

saw.connect(context.destination);

sine.start();
saw.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup is fine. Just try changing the frequency of the modulator and add a little more gain, and you'll see that you're in fact doing FM. For example:

```
sine.frequency.value = 15;
sineGain.gain.value = 100;
```

will definitely tell you that it works.

Comment: Exactly - you have to remember the range at each point.  The oscillator goes from -1 to 1, but only a +/- 1Hz change in frequency might not make much difference.